# sql error after update editor for EE3

Tags: devdemon, ee3, update, editor

after a successfull EE3 update, I also updated editor to 4.0.3. I replaced whole editor directory in systen/addons and themes. update was performed and version now is 4.0.3

when clicking on settings for editor, or editing an existing fieldtype I get this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'editor_m_Config_editor_configs.id' in 'field list':
SELECT editor_m_Config_editor_configs.id as editor_m_Config__id, editor_m_Config_editor_configs.site_id as editor_m_Config__site_id, editor_m_Config_editor_configs.label as editor_m_Config__label, editor_m_Config_editor_configs.type as editor_m_Config__type, editor_m_Config_editor_configs.settings as editor_m_Config__settings FROM (`exp_editor_configs` as editor_m_Config_editor_configs) LIMIT 18446744073709551615

/home/thomas.hartmann/htdocs/ee3/system/ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:119

it searches for column "id", but in my table "exp_editor_configs" the column is called "config_id"

Comment: a new install of the add-on solves the problem fifty-fifty. I see that the exp_editor_configs table has a new structure. but by unintall/reinstall the add-on, all my actual fieldtypes with editor are gone. in my opinion, the update process from 3.2.4 to 4.0.3 does not update the tables correctly.

do I have to update 3.2.4 first to 4.0.3 on my EE2 instance, before installing the 4.0.3 version for EE3?

Comment: update from 3.2.4 on EE2 is not possible, there is no 4.0.3 version on EE2. so the only way I know, is update 3.2.4 to 4.0.3 on my EE3 instance, which causes then the missing columns error.

Comment: We are dealing with the same error after upgrading to EE 3.5.6 and Editor version 4.0.3. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: It's been a while, but any solution ever posted?